# backward elimination in R

Tags: r

I am trying to get the final model using backward elimination with R but I got the following error message when I ran the code. Could anyone please help me this?

```
base<-lm(Eeff~NDF,data=phuong)
fullmodel<-lm(Eeff~NDF+ADF+CP+NEL+DMI+FCM,data=phuong)
 step(full, direction = "backward", trace=FALSE )

> Error in step(full, direction = "backward", trace = FALSE) : 
number of rows in use has changed: remove missing values?
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When comparing different submodels, it is necessary that they be fitted to the same set of data -- otherwise the results just don't make sense. (Consider the extreme situation where you have two predictors `A` and `B`, which are each measured on only half of your observations -- then the model `y~A+B` will be fitted to all the data, but the models `y~A` and `y~B` will be fitted to **non-overlapping** subsets of the data.)  Thus, `step` won't allow you to compare submodels that (because of automatic removal of cases containing `NA` values) are using different subsets of the original data set.

Using `na.omit` on the original data set should fix the problem.

```
fullmodel <- lm(Eeff ~ NDF + ADF + CP + NEL + DMI + FCM, data = na.omit(phuong))
step(fullmodel, direction = "backward", trace=FALSE )
```

However, if you have a lot of `NA` values in different predictors, you may end up losing a lot of your data set -- in an extreme case you could lose the *entire* data set.  If this happens you have to reconsider your modeling strategy ...

Comment: I've got a doubt, don't you have to put  fullmodel instead of full in step(full, direction = "backward", trace=FALSE )? Am I wrong?

Comment: yes. I just copied the OP's code without looking at it too carefully.  Thanks.

Comment: yeah, it works. Thank you very much Ben Bolker for your comments.

Comment: Another question arise is that could we do the same'backward elimination' as above but now not using the linear regression (lm) but mixed model (lmer) instead?
fullmodel<-lmer(Eeff~NDF+ADF+CP+NEL+DMI+FCM + (1|Study),data=na.omit(phuong))
step(fullmodel, direction = "backward", trace=FALSE )

Comment: I believe `drop1` works for `lmer` fits, but it looks like `step` doesn't.  May I also caution you against stepwise approaches?  There are *some* contexts where they make sense, but most of the time they're a bad idea -- try Googling "Harrell stepwise" to read some of the critiques.