# What is an alternative to leap() that can handle NAs?

Tags: r, na, genetics

Need to apply [Branch and bound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_and_bound) method to choose best model. `leaps()` from leaps package works well, only if the data has no `NA` values, otherwise throws an error:

```
#dummy data
x<-matrix(rnorm(100),ncol=4)
#convert to 0,1,2 - this is a genetic data, NA=NoCall
x<-matrix(round(runif(100)*10) %% 3,ncol=4)
#introduce NA=NoCall
x[1,1] <-NA
#response, case or control
y<-rep(c(0,1,1,0,1),5)
leaps(x,y)

Error in leaps.setup(x, y, wt = wt, nbest = nbest, nvmax = NCOL(x) + int,  : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 4)
```

Using only `complete.cases()` is not an option as I lose 80% of data.

What is an alternative to `leap` that can handle `NA`s? I am writing my own function to do something similar, but it is getting big and clunky, I feel like I am reinventing the wheel...

**UPDATE:**
I have tried using `stepAIC()`, facing the same problem of missing data:

```
Error in stepAIC(fit) : 
  number of rows in use has changed: remove missing values?
```

Comment: would imputing the NA be reasonable for your data? and is `stepAIC()` (forward and back) really no good?

Comment: Imputation is not an option. Does `stepAIC()` go through every possible combination?

Comment: no `MASS::stepAIC()` like `step()` does forward, back or both. Usually finds same model as `leaps()` for most datasets (I think???).

Comment: OK, need a big picture clarification; how are you thinking to compare two models that are built on different data sets?  Or is that part of the question?

Comment: @Aaron with worry that this post turns into stats, I will give more details: with ~50 variables, intention is to build best possible model (prefer AIC, but can be anything). To calculate all possible combinations for 50 variables is not feasible, hence thought of using branch and bound. Ideally I need, `function(data, glm(outcome~all combinations), bootstrap=1000, return(best model(AIC)))`

Comment: This part of it, though, is a stats problem, as AIC can't compare models built with different data sets.  So to compare models with and without certain variables, you need to remove the rows with missing values for those variables.  You may need to "reconsider your modeling strategy", to quote [Ben Bolker](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11767674/210673).  Otherwise you may also want to look into variants of AIC, a quick Google search brings up a [recent JASA article](http://dx.doi.org/10.1198/016214508000001057) that might be a good starting point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This is a stats problem, as AIC can't compare models built with
>   different data sets. So to compare models with and without certain
>   variables, you need to remove the rows with missing values for those
>   variables. You may need to "reconsider your modeling strategy", [to
>   quote Ben
>   Bolker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11767602/backward-elimination-in-r/11767674#11767674).
>   Otherwise you may also want to look into variants of AIC, a quick
>   Google search brings up a recent [JASA
>   article](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1198/016214508000001057)
>   that might be a good starting point.

[- Aaron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/210673)

Comment: I am getting the exact same error while I am using `bestglm(train, IC="AIC")`. My dataframe has no null rather some zeros.

Answer (score 1):

you may try bestglm::bestglm where branch-bound method can be specified. The NAs can be handled by na.action argument as it in glm. see here for additional information:
http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bestglm/vignettes/bestglm.pdf

Comment: Thanks for referring to `bestglm` package, didn't know about it. This package also requires elimination of `NA` rows, which I am trying to avoid.